# GSAP animations: scale vs height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

When using GSAP to perform a transition where an element is scaled equally in both dimensions, there seems to be a choice between using `scale`, or both `height` and `width`.

Which is better, as in will result in a higher frame rate? Or if there are conditions on the element / other transitions / DOM / CSS / browser / processor / GPU (/anything else?) that makes one better over the other, what are these?

Answer (score 3):

One of the differences in using Scale Vs Width/Height is the use of CSS but you have to keep in mind while using Scale it will resize from the center of the object, while using Width/Height it will be from top left. Unless you change the transform Origin.

One major factor is the content of the object you are resizing, if you use Scale and the object has content, it will also scale everything inside, while Width/Height will not.

Comment: You can easily set the origin of the transformation for scaling: scaleX:2.0, transformOrigin:"50% 50%"

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, what `scaleX` and `scaleY` do is that they use CSS's `transform` in the background and generally, using transforms produces a much smoother result because of sub-pixel rendering. Also, if you add `force3D: true` on the same element as well, it forces it to render it on its own GPU layer hence, hardware accelerated. And that happens because it adds `translate3d: (0px, 0px, 0px)` onto the same element. So in my opinion, manipulating `transform` related properties is much better.

Although, **[this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)** by **Paul Irish** 
talks about *moving* elements (i.e. moving with `translate` vs `top` and `left`), but I believe the same holds true in our case.

Here is a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7ttc2hk/) for you to play around with.